# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while trying to scale

Tags: java, scale, bufferedimage, libvlc, vlcj

Have been trying to scale down a view to different scale but i'm having some troubles. The context is inside a video player (using VLCJ).

This code is being used to scale the image but after the first frame the image stops updating with next image for some reason.

```
public void newFrameRecieved(int[] rgbBuffer)
{
    this.image.setRGB(0, 0, this.size.width, this.size.height, rgbBuffer, 0, this.size.width);


    after = new BufferedImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this.image.getType());
    at = new AffineTransform();
    scalingFactorX = (double)this.getWidth()/ (double)this.image.getWidth();
    scalingFactorY = (double)this.getHeight()/ (double)this.image.getHeight();
    at.scale(scalingFactorX, scalingFactorY);
    scaleOp = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
    this.image = scaleOp.filter(this.image, after);


    repaint();
}
```

If the middle part (all code between this.image.setRGB(......) and repaint();) is removed then it works(except the scaling part...)

Would really appreciate any help you guys can offer!
The error recieved is the following:

```
JNA: Callback uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.direct.DefaultDirectMediaPlayer$DisplayCallback@4516af24 threw the following exception:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!
    at sun.awt.image.IntegerInterleavedRaster.setDataElements(IntegerInterleavedRaster.java:301)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.setRGB(BufferedImage.java:1059)
    at myVlcjWrapper.VideoSurfacePanel.newFrameRecieved(VideoSurfacePanel.java:65)
```

I understand the problem I'm just clueless as to how to fix it!
Thanks!

Comment: how large is your image you are trying to scale? in pixels

Comment: What does `image.setRGB` do?

Comment: Since it's a video stream in reality I can't say I'm sertain.. But I am pretty sure it's 1920x1080!

Comment: Simplified image.setRGB writes the buffer to the image.

Comment: The stack trace clearly shows it's the `setRGB` invocation that throws the exception... So I think you "accidentally" fixed a mistake somewhere, in addition to commenting out the code, when it "worked".

Comment: No I'm sertain I only commented it out!  Also it works the first time data is passed through the buffer.. I was thinking if my code for some reason modified the source image with the line this.image = scaleOp.filter(....);

Comment: I don't doubt you're certain. ;-) I'm just telling you that the stack trace says otherwise. You don't get past the first line in your method. The problem is that your `size` member variable doesn't match the dimensions of what is passed in as `rgbBuffer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing alot of error searching I ended up with this piece of working code!

```
public void newFrameRecieved(int[] rgbBuffer, Dimension max)
{
    before = new BufferedImage(max.width, max.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    before.setRGB(0, 0, max.width, max.height, rgbBuffer, 0, max.width);
    after = new BufferedImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this.image.getType());
    at = new AffineTransform();
    scalingFactorX = (double)after.getWidth()/ (double)before.getWidth();
    scalingFactorY = (double)after.getHeight()/ (double)before.getHeight();
    at.scale(scalingFactorX, scalingFactorY);
    scaleOp = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
    this.image = scaleOp.filter(before, after);

    repaint();
}
```

It's a minimal change but it did the trick! Thought it best to post it in case anyone ever finds their way here again.
Thanks for the help guys! :)